# why google drive does not return metadata of files which i provided in the fields parameter?

Tags: javascript, axios, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the Size of files with google drive API

```
const filesFilteredByDate = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
   q: `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`,
    fields: 'files(id, name, size, modifiedTime)',
    orderBy: 'modifiedTime desc',
    spaces: 'drive',
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  });
```

But it does not return the size and modified time of the folder
[image]

So how do i get size , modifiedTime and createdTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of the folder is not provided by google drive api more id, name,kind,mimeType are the default data object

Moreover, put your fields inside params if you are using Axios just like that

```
const filesFilteredByDate = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
            params: {
                q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                fields: "files(id,name,createdTime,modifiedTime,parents)",
                orderBy: "modifiedTime desc",
            },
            headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all file types have a size. your searching for folders only folders dont return a size.

```
{
   "id": "1R_QjyKy27C-3ASMJJa",
   "name": "YouTube",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "modifiedTime": "2021-12-14T08:48:38.786Z"
  },
```

If you try a diffrent file type you will find it does return a size fore example a zip file

```
 {
   "id": "107GrdcfBFVuWjlMZEKN7qAqsdvsH",
   "name": "backup_2022-02-16-1013_Daimto_e3763aa68b2c-others.zip",
   "modifiedTime": "2022-02-16T08:14:16.917Z",
   "size": "17849423"
  },
```

Comment: I understand about size but Is anything wrong with my API request it does not return ModifiedTime or any other field which I provide? @DaImTo